# Вывод текста на LayeredWindow делфи

Tags: delphi, windows, форма, текст, png

Есть PNG-картинка, которую я накладываю на форму. Естественно, перед этим форму делаю "слоеной". Затем вызываю `UpdateLayeredWindow` со всеми необходимыми параметрами. Все чудесно. И форма показана, и PNG применен как полагается.

НО

В один прекрасный день я решил вывести что-то наподобие Caption для этой формы. Я просто вывел текст на заранее приготовленный битмап, а потом снова использовал `UpdateLayeredWindow`. К моему удивлению, выведенный текст стал "прозрачным" для кликов. То есть если мое окно находится над любым текстовым редактором, то при наведении курсора мыши на текст, курсор принимает вид как при вводе текста.

**Собственно, вопрос**: действительно ли можно вывести текст корректно на Layered-окно или это невозможно в принципе. На заметку: GDI+ даже не рассматриваю.

Пример того, как это выглядит приведен ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Коричневый фон - мое PNG изображение. Если нужно - скажите, я выложу его здесь.

**Решение**
Возможно, имеется лучшее решение описанной проблемы, но я нашел пока только такое.
Предположим, что готовый к выводу битмап у нас имеется и у него также есть прозрачность. Тогда загружаем этот битмап в экземпляр класса `TBitmap` и делаем его копию на сторонний битмап. После этого, выводим текст, картинки и т.п. на сделанной копии, затем вызываем процедуру `CopyAlphaChannel` чтобы восстановить прозрачность пикселей, затертых выводом текста, картинок и т.п.
В конце концов нам необходимо скопировать полученное изображение на оригинальный битмап и передать его в качестве одного из параметров для функции `UpdateLayeredWindow`.

Примерный код:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  OutBmp, B: TBitmap;
begin
// Здесь уже должны быть сделаны все приготовления для вывода OutBmp с помощью функции UpdateLayeredWindow

// Создаем наш битмап для вывода текста
B := TBitmap.Create;
B.Width := OutBmp.Width;
B.Height := OutBmp.Height;
B.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

// Делаем копию оригинального битмапа
B.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, OutBmp);

// Выводим текст, например
B.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
B.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
B.Canvas.Font.Color := clYellow;
B.Canvas.Font.Size := 11;
B.Canvas.TextOut(4, 4, 'Simple txt string');
B.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;

// Собственно, цель этого куска кода - восстановление затертой альфы
CopyAlphaChannel(OutBmp, B);

// Копируем буфер обратно на оригинал
OutBmp.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, B);

B.Free;

// Далее OutBmp передается как один из параметров для UpdateLayeredWindow
end;
```

Теперь очередь процедуры по копированию альфа-канала:

```
procedure CopyAlphaChannel(ABmpIn, ABmpOut: TBitmap);
type
  TRGBAArray = array[Word] of TRGBQuad;
  PRGBAArray = ^TRGBAArray;
var
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  RowIn: PRGBAArray;
  RowOut: PRGBAArray;
begin
  // ABmpIn - битмап, содержащий альфа-канал
  if not Assigned(ABmpIn) or not Assigned(ABmpOut) then
    Exit;

  for Y:=0 to ABmpIn.Height - 1 do
    begin
      RowIn := ABmpIn.ScanLine[Y];
      RowOut := ABmpOut.ScanLine[Y];
      for X:=0 to ABmpIn.Width - 1 do
        RowOut[X].rgbReserved := RowIn[X].rgbReserved;
    end;
end;
```

В результате, получаем такое изображение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы за этот текст окно таскать хотите? немного не понятен вопрос. Вас смущает что курсор меняется,  или прозрачность для кликов. И что значит Вывести текст корректно?. Добавьте текст в саму png, как вариант, если там нет никакой динамической информации и с ним делать ничего не надо.

Comment: @teran, да, хотелось бы за этот текст "таскать" форму по экрану, в связи с этим добавление текста в исходный PNG-файл это не то, что требуется.  Корректно вывести текст - значит вывести текст на Layered окне так, как он выводится на обычном окне - то есть чтобы текст не был прозрачным для кликов мыши. На картинке в вопросе, если кликнуть по тексту, то Layered окно потеряет фокус, а получит фокус окно редактора кода IDE.

Comment: Вам нужно было именно этот вопрос и задать. Сейчас из прочтения вопроса складывается впечатление, что у Вас проблема в графике, а не во взаимодействием мыши с Вашим окном. Вы и картинку привели очевидно с этой (графической) проблемой.

Comment: @mega, возможно, действительно сумбурно описал проблему. Прошу прощения. Тем не менее, есть ли у Вас какие-либо варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: для прозрачных окон так задумано, вот аналогичный вопрос на en.so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086006/win32-edit-controls-of-ws-ex-layered-parent-dont-receive-mouse-click-events-when

Comment: @mega, вопрос по ссылке не относится к моей проблеме. У меня сложилось такое впечатление, что выводимый на битмап текст просто затирает альфу битмапа и получается "прозрачным" для кликов, в то время, как остальная часть формы ведет себя как обычно. Только непонятно мне, как же не затирать альфа-значение пикселей находящихся под текстом.

Comment: Расширил ответ. Кстати насколько я понимаю, Вы же не прозрачный текст хотите рисовать? Значит Вам не 1 надо выставлять в альфа-канал, а 255, только выставляйте все таки TRANSPARENT, чтобы оставить фон текста прозрачным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Собственно, вопрос: действительно ли можно вывести текст корректно на
>   Layered-окно или это невозможно в принципе.

Насчет красного фона текста, это вполне решаемо, независимо от типа прозрачности: просто перед выводом текста выставьте прозрачный фоновый режим в `hdc` через `SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT)`.

> @mega, вопрос по ссылке не относится к моей проблеме. У меня сложилось
>   такое впечатление, что выводимый на битмап текст просто затирает альфу
>   битмапа и получается "прозрачным" для кликов, в то время, как
>   остальная часть формы ведет себя как обычно. Только непонятно мне, как
>   же не затирать альфа-значение пикселей находящихся под текстом.

По ссылке дают решение как раз, когда надо отключить виндовую фичу с прозрачностью для кликов мыши. Эта фича позволяет делать формы произвольной формы, и они гармонично вписываются в интерфейс Windows.

При выводе на форму, надо в альфа-канал вместо нуля писать единицу. Это ни как не отразится на прозрачности текста, Вы даже не увидите эту долю процента, но эта единица вернет функциональность для мыши.

Ноль в альфаканал выставляют стандартные функции GDI (TextOut, DrawText и т.п.).

Я бы попробовал сделать так:

1. Готовим DIB-секцию нужного Вам размера, на котором Вы будете рисовать.
2. Заливаем ее нейтральным цветом
3. Пишем в ней нужный текст
4. Проходимся по памяти DIB'а и выставляем везде alpha=1
5. Выводим DIB на форму с помощью AlphaBlend (выбираем ключ прозрачности, который использовали на шаге 2)

Насколько я знаю, GDI+, который Вы сразу отмели, умеет делать аналогичные вещи, от программиста в таком случае глубоких знаний GDI не требуется.

Т.е. если бы вопрос стоял "как бы мне это сделать", а не "как это работает", то я бы наверное все же вернулся к GDI+.

p.s.: кстати насколько я понимаю, Вы же не прозрачный текст хотите рисовать? Значит Вам не 1 надо выставлять в альфа-канал, а 255.

Comment: Да, тоже вчера подумал про восстановление альфы и все-таки решил этот вопрос. Во всяком случае, для моих нужд решения достаточно вполне. Хотя я уверен, что если подумать еще, то можно оптимизировать тот код, который есть в моем вопросе. Приму Ваш ответ, поскольку некоторые мысли в нем и натолкули на ответ. З.Ы. Повысить рейтинг Вашего ответа не могу из-за ограничений, извиняйте))

Comment: Для тех, кто интересуется проблемой - ответ добавлен в "тело" вопроса. Там же есть некоторый код.